# What's a word for "fear of breaking the law" or "fear of breaking rules"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

There are many great "-phobia" words, but I need one to mean "fear of breaking the law" or "fear of breaking rules"?

Example intended usage from my article: "There is a curious aversion to illegal positions in chess. I feel it myself - a sense that the fabric of reality itself may even break down. In logic, the Principle of Explosion says one can prove anything from a contradiction. But in chess, this xyz-phobia is unfounded."

- Does a word for this exist already? (I have been looking at various phobia lists online, but can't find anything like this.)
- If no such word exists currently, what is a plausible coinage?

EDIT: A useful page seems to be https://glosbe.com/en/grc/transgress, but many of the words may have religious connotations?

EDIT2: Current best candidate = Delinquophobia

Comment: That's a good phrase

Comment: https://www.treatmyocd.com/what-is-ocd/common-fears/fear-of-breaking-the-law-ocd

Comment: I don't see how impossible chess positions is an example of breaking the law.  It's not impossible to break the law, but impossible chess positions are positions that could not occur if the rules were followed.  Also, the sense that reality is crumbling when looking at an impossible chess position is like a fear that a law has been broken already. It's like anxiety some people feel when looking at a surreal painting.

Comment: FIDE have Laws of Chess, so breaking the law in that sense, not felony

Comment: Hello, Laska. This could be a lacuna. Googling "fear of breaking the law" turns up quite a few hits, but OCD is the term usually applied, and this is a gross hypernym. // Sorry, ELU does not deal with suggested candidate words. These need a certain currency before they are accepted into the lexicon. Really good authors manage it on occasion (_impartial, invulnerable, lacklustre, laughable, lonely, madcap, majestic, mimic, monumental, moonbeam; butterfingers;  chortle; pandemonium; robot; serendipity; Utopia; hobbit; quidditch_ ...).

Comment: Why not just delete the *xyz-* and write *But in chess, this phobia is unfounded.*?  The previous-but-one sentence explains the nature of the phobia, pulling a word like *delinquophobia* out of your dictionary won't make the sentence more expressive (it'll just confuse 99% of readers) or more eloquent (99% of readers will have to read it twice, at least, to have a good grasp of the word),.

Comment: Could you Post a less-opinionated, more useful example? How could aversion to illegal positions in Chess or any other field be considered 'curious'? Further, please refer back to High Performance Mark (above).

Comment: @High Performance. That's a good idea, but I think it's fun for the readership to encounter a novel word. I would put it in inverted commas maybe.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin The example is just a fragment from a technical article for experts - I hope the whole shows whimsy and self-critique. Anyway, there is no requirement that real-world examples have any prose virtue at all: they are just examples

Comment: Thanks and that doesn't stop both the Question and any Answer from being largely opinion-based. Don't you think any example that's 'just a fragment from a technical article for experts' either belongs in a forum for those experts, or should be fully quoted? How do whimsy or self-critique, real-world examples having prose virtue or it being fun for your readership to encounter novel words matter here? How could any of those affect the Question, or any Answers?

Comment: Is it in the same sense as "fear of committing a crime" or is it  just about breaking the rules in a system, like a game (as in, your 'illegal move' example in chess)? The latter is more like "fear of making mistakes" as well; thus, it is not as strong as "fear of breaking the law(s)" perhaps. Please clarify or give other examples if possible. For example, _peccatophobia_ is the fear of committing a sin or crime.

Comment: Peccatophobia is perfect thanks